# How to execute FindOne() with logical query selector($or) in Official Go MongoDB driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I am a beginner in mongo with go. I am trying to find one document where `"username"` or `email` will be matched. But can't figure out the way to implement this condition to filter.

Here is my document model:

```
type User struct {
    Username  string    `json:"username" bson:"username"`
    Email     string    `json:"email" bson:"email"`
    Password  string    `json:"password" bson:"password"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at" bson:"updated_at"`
}
```

And the query:

```
filter := bson.D{
   {"username", user.Username},
   {"$or": {"email", user.Email}},
}

err = userCollection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filter).Decode(&user)
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use `$or$` as below:

```
filter := bson.D{
   {"$or":[{"username": user.Username},{"email": user.Email}]},}
```

Comment: It throws an error with `syntax error: unexpected {, expecting expression`.

Comment: add semicolon at the end

Answer (score 0):

Finally this method worked for me.

```
filter := bson.D{{
        "$or",
        bson.A{
            bson.D{
                {"username", user.Username},
            },
            bson.D{
                {"email", user.Email},
            },
        },
    }}
```

Some info for constructing commands:

- `D: A BSON document. This type should be used in situations where order matters, such as MongoDB commands.`
- `M: An unordered map. It is the same as D, except it does not preserve order.`
- `A: A BSON array.`
- `E: A single element inside a D.`